# Remove pod dependency based on platform

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I'm adding an apple watch extension to my project and I'd like to use the same pods I'm using for my main iOS app. However, the podspec I'm using for my iOS app has a dependency that causes an error when I include the watch extension as a target in my podfile. Is there a way to remove dependencies based on platform (ios, watchos)?

The error:

`` [!] The platform of the target `My Watch Extension` (watchOS 5.2) is not compatible with `Library X (10.1.19)`, which does not support `watchos`. ``

So far I'm doing the following in my podfile:

```
target 'My Watch Extension' do
    platform :watchos, '5.2'
    pod 'MyPod', :path => 'MyPod'
end
```

And I added the following to my podspec:

```
s.platforms = { :ios => "10.0", :watchos => "5.2"}
```

Is it possible to have to separate podspecs?

Answer (score 1):

You can set different dependencies for different platforms

```
  spec.dependency 'Alamofire'
  spec.ios.dependency 'Crashlytics'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of my podfile.  I just include different pod's for the different targets.

```
def external_dependencies
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher'
end

def caller_id_external_dependencies
  pod 'GMCPagingScrollView'
  pod 'KeychainAccess'
end

target 'Goob' do
  external_dependencies
  internal_dependencies

  target 'UnitTests' do
    pod 'Firebase/Core'
    pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
    pod 'SQLite.swift/SQLCipher'

    inherit! :search_paths
  end

end

target 'GoobCallerId' do
  caller_id_external_dependencies
end
```

Comment: The problem is the podspec file has a dependency listed. So on one platform (iOS) i want the dependency, while on another platform (watchOS) I don't want the dependency.

Comment: The only way we've worked around similar issues is by making our own local version of the podSpec and removing the dependency to use for the watch target.

Comment: Also, is the watch OS actually using the functionality of the pod spec, or is it just a pain to decouple the functionality?  If its just problems with decoupling, you can stub in an alternate version of that podspec that the podfile points to for the watch target.

Comment: Ya I'd like to avoid decoupling unless its absolutely needed. So we need a version of the podspec for iOS with all the dependencies and another version of watchOS without the dependencies. Were you able to get something similar working?

Comment: Yes, I did.  A few pods really go overboard with dependencies.

Comment: How did you get that to work? I dont have an idea of how to specify a specific podspec for the watch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199336/discussion-between-halr-and-brosef).